# SH script - passed variable (file name) with space

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sh

I am honestly a bit disappointed in myself but I've spent a few hours trying to search this down successfully. The topic has been covered in a number of threads but I just can't get to a resolution.

I have a 'sh' script (on a busybox or I'd use full bash).

The script is called externally and passed 3 variables ($1, $2, $3) where:

```
$1 directory of file
$2 not used
$3 name of file including directory
```

I'm trying to get the file size (stat is not available) so I'm trying to use du:

pseudo:

```
filesize=$(du $3 | awk '{ print $1 }')
```

I just can't get the script to process filenames with spaces correctly. 
I've tried quoting and escape quoting to no avail. 
At the command prompt I can inject the \ to handle white space for du.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you calling the script?

Comment: `du "$3"` should work.

Comment: The script has be chmod a+x and is being called as both "sh script" and ./script.

Comment: du "$3" does not work

Comment: 1) Put `set -ex` at the top of the script. 2) What does `file "$3"` show?

Comment: All the knowledgable posters here seem to agree double-quoting should work. You claim it does not. The only reasonable conclusion is that you haven't explained well enough what exactly you're doing which isn't working. Important details you've dropped: the code you're running (a minimal working example to demonstrate the problem), how you run it (the full command line), and the result/error message your getting.  I guarantee you'd find a solution to you problem if you do that, instead of continuing this endless "this should work"/"it does not" loop.

Comment: Extending @shx2's comment: it's likely there's another problem involved, such as the script being called wrong (e.g. the filename isn't properly quoted when passed to the script, meaning that part of it is in $3, part in $4, and maybe parts in $5, $6, etc...) `set -x` is very useful for figuring out exactly what's going on inside a script. Also, try running the script through [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net), and see if it spots anything obvious.

Comment: Perhaps the file name not only contains spaces, but a newline, in which case you probably aren't really passing in the full file name as an argument...

Comment: @shx2, et. al: I agree and this is part of where the frustration on my side originates from (and the delay in a response). I'm trying to simplify code so that I can provide a reproducible example.

Comment: What does `I just can't get the script to process filenames with spaces correctly.` mean? You're getting a syntax error? Other error message? Incorrect output (and if so what is expected and actual)? Something else? Post a sample file name and the result of running your command. What happens when you try it with a hard-coded filname? What if you use a variable with file name assigned instead of $3? Basically - think about it and then post your findings to help us to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Double-quoting works is `sh`.

```
sh-3.2$ f="a b"
sh-3.2$ echo aaaa > "$f"
sh-3.2$ ls -l "a b"
-rw-r--r--  1 xxxx  xxxxx  5 May 23 xx:xx a b
sh-3.2$ du "$f"
8   a b
```

Comment: Calling ' du "$f" ' from within a script is where the problem lies and du "$f" does not work (same as du "$3" above)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
    filesize=`du "$3" | awk '{ print $1 }'`
```

Comment: Why would you switch from `$()` to backticks?!

Comment: Same result, file not found

Comment: the $() didn't work for me in the sh.  Reading original question again.. Busybox seem to be using ash so it should support $().  In bash.. $() worked for me.   Script is called like this.  `script dir arg2 "dir with space" `

Answer (score 0):

I am very thankful for those who took the time to provide some ideas on this issue. After a long time and much effort, it was determined that the busybox implementation was the culprit.

Everything provided above was valid provided a more current version of bb was used (or any full distro). Unfortunately it took significant trial and error to get to the cause.